# Setting up ruby rails with vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, bundle, vagrantfile

I am looking to set up ruby on rails in a vagrant machine in a Windows environment. I have loaded the vagrant machine but have had to destroy it multiple times as I have messed it up a few times. Could anyone point me in the direction of a definitive guide as to how to set it up successfully or provide indications as to what I need to do. So far I have installed ruby.

When i run ruby -v in my windows environment I get:

```
ruby 2.3.0p0
```

My vagrantfile, minus commented out lines, is as follows:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

end
```

When i putty into vagrant I firstly:

```
cd /vagrant
```

When I run ruby -v I get

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux]
```

When i run which -a ruby

```
/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/ruby
```

On previous attempts I had ran

```
bundle install
```

but it was not installed yet. I was told by a colleague to run:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```

I then ran

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-bundler
```

Now when I run

```
which -a ruby
```

I get

```
/usr/bin/ruby
/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/ruby
```

I believe this is due to running sudo apt-get install ruby-bundler. Therefore I was wondering where do i go from here? I have, on previous attempts gotten as far as bundle install which just freezes and had tried a single gem install but got a permission error. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: you should use `ubuntu/precise64` its more recent, not sure exactly which version of ruby they ship but will be better

Comment: Thanks will do that and get back to you.